# Problema ao eliminar da memória um TObjectList<TLabel>

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, embarcadero

estou com um problema para limpar da memoria um TObjectList< TLabel>,
em especifico o ObjectList do tipo TLabel.
Eu criei duas ObjectList, adicionei um item e tentei limpar elas da memoria:
Trecho do código:

```
  tolRectMenuItemProntuario := TObjectList<TRectangle>.Create;
  tlLabelDadosPaciente := TObjectList<TLabel>.Create();
  tlLabelDadosPaciente.Add(lbTituloConvenio);
  tolRectMenuItemProntuario.Add(rtMenuItemAnamnese);      
  tolRectMenuItemProntuario:= nil;
  tolRectMenuItemProntuario.DisposeOf;
  tlLabelDadosPaciente := nil;
  tlLabelDadosPaciente.DisposeOf;
```

Entretanto ao deletar tentar deletar a tlLabelDadosPaciente, a TObjectList< TLabel>, o sistema da erro:

"*Project AppSIGMedOffLine.exe raised exception class EInvalidPointer with message 'Invalid pointer operation'.*"

Existe alguma forma diferente de deletar um TObjectList< TLabel>, pois eu estou utilizando da mesma forma os dois ObjectList, mas só o TLabel da erro.

Comment: Seria bom adicionar um exemplo mínimo e completo para que alguém pudesse reproduzir o que você está encontrando...

Answer (score 0):

Você está atribuindo `nil` para a variável antes de executar o `DisposeOf`. Você teria de fazer essa atribuição somente após executar o método de liberação da memória. Ainda assim, acho que você deve  chamar o método `.Free` ao invés do Dispose. E também, ao criar `TObjectList` passe `false` como parâmetro. Se fizer assim, `TObjectList` não irá destruir os objetos quando ele mesmo for destruído. Passe `true` apenas se você cria os objetos em tempo de execução e/ou deseja que a lista os destrua.